# Header for nested C++ lambda function

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, c++14, header-files

Consider the following (simplified) example where two lambda functions call each other, one of which also takes another function as an argument. I need to use lambda functions, since the functions also pass modified, nested functions between each other.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

auto f = [](int n, auto h)
{
    if(n >= 5) return n;
    cout << "h is some function " << h(4.0) << end; 
    auto func = [](int m){ return m*h(m); }; // some nested function   
    return g(n+1,func);  
};

auto g = [](int n, auto h)
{
    if(n >= 5) return n;
    cout << "h is some function " << h(5.0) << end; 
    auto func = [](int m){ return m*h(m); }; // some nested function   
    return f(n+1,func); 
};

int main()
{
    auto initial_function = [](int m){ return m*m; };
    f(1, initial_function);
    return 0.0;
}
```

This returns the usual error *undeclared identifier 'g'* which was to expect since there is no header file. So my question is: What is the proper syntax to declare the two lambda functions?

Comment: Write old boring named functions.

Comment: Aside, `auto f(1);` doesn't call `f`.

Comment: I have adjusted my above example. While several of the answers given below seem to answer the original formulation of my problem, I have now made the problem more realistic: g itself also takes another function as an argument.

Comment: I understand wondering how to do this, ***but***..: If you actually have the need to do this in _real_ code, you have a serious design problem that once fixed will make this a moot point.

Comment: The answer to the updated question is "write old boring named functions (or function templates)".

Comment: what are "old boring named functions". Do you refer to 'not lambda' functions? If so, this is not a solution to my problem.

Comment: Regarding your edit, `f` is still calling `g` as though it were unary. Put a little more thought into your question, please. And your "problem" appears 100% fabricated.

Comment: what do you mean by "fabricated"?

Comment: [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: An XY problem indeed. Quite insightful. I have adjusted the above problem, so that now this should not be a problem anymore.

Comment: Your updated question is still asking about lambdas, which are totally uncalled for in this situation. The answer is still "don't use lambdas".

Comment: Aside, if you are talking to a specific commenter, tag their name like this: @user56643, otherwise they may or may not be alerted about your comments,

Comment: @n.m. Yes, I was indeed producing an XY problem. I have now adjusted the problem so that it really comes very close to the real problem that I have. The problem is not fabricated, I have two functions that iteratively take derivatives of each other (the problem arises from the use of Ito's lemma in compound option pricing).

Comment: Except that in your question you _don't_ have functions; you have lambdas. Indeed, the solution to your actual posted question is to use functions, as @n.m. has repeatedly said.

Comment: Thanks @n.m. and @ildjarn, you were of course right. User @Mzhr finally my question. I didn't know how to pass functions between `non-lambda functions', which is why I was initially insisting on the usage of lambdas. I will refrain from abstracting my problems too much ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works on my machine:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

extern function<int(int, function<int(int)>)> g;

auto f = [](int n, function<int(int)> h)
{
    if (n >= 5) return n;
    cout << "h is some function " << h(4.0) << endl;
    auto func = [h](int m) { return m*h(m); };   
    return g(n + 1, func);
};

function<int(int, function<int(int)>)> g = [](int n, function<int(int)> h)
{
    if (n >= 5) return n;
    cout << "h is some function " << h(5.0) << endl;
    auto func = [h](int m) { return m*h(m); };   
    return f(n + 1, func);
};

int main()
{
    auto initial_function = [](int m) { return m*m; };
    f(1, initial_function);

    getchar();
    return 0; // Return value of the function is int so its better to use 0 rather than 0.0
}
```

Comment: Indeed, this works for the original formulation of the problem. See my modification above. The function g now takes itself another function as input argument. The problem is that std::function cannot handle 'auto' as type. How to work around this?

Comment: User @Mzhr answered finally my question. I didn't know how to pass functions between `non-lambda functions', which is why I was initially insisting on the usage of lambdas.

Answer (score 2):

You need to capture the lambda inside `g` (or vice versa). `g` and `f`  are variables which are **pointing** to a (unnamed) function. Making these lambdas doesn't make sense. Lambdas work best when you need a function in local scope.  You will have to convert at-least one of them as a function and do a forward-declare for it to get this code working

```
int f(int n);
auto g = [](int n)
{
     if(n >= 5) return n;
    return f(n+1); 
};

int f(int n)
{
    if(n >= 5) return n;
    return g(n+1);  
}

int main()
{
    f(1);
    return 0.0;
}
```

Based on OP's edit, probably what the OP needs is

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto g(int n, const T1& f, const T2& h)
{ 
    if(n >= 5) return n;
    cout << "h is some function " << h(5.0) << end; 
    return f(n+1); 
}
```

To be called as:

```
auto h = [](int m) { return m*m; };
auto f = [h](int m) { return n >= 5 ? n : return g(n+1, f, h); };
g(n, f, h);
```

Comment: The proposed solution solves the example, but does not retain full generality. The functions f and g I have mentioned need to be lambda functions of type auto, that themselves also take other functions as input arguments. See my modified example above.

Comment: @user56643 I edited my answer based on your edits. But still using all lambdas doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

Use std::function to address the issue.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

std::function<int(int)> f;
std::function<int(int)> g;    

int main()
{

   f = [](int n)
   {
     if(n >= 5) return n;
     return g(n+1);  
   };

   g = [](int n)
   {
      if(n >= 5) return n;
      return f(n+1); 
   };

    std::cout << f(1) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have added #include <functional> and run the code. It returns the error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations.

Comment: Move assignment of f and g inside main ()

Comment: This switches everything to runtime polymorphism, which sort of defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The type of a lambda is not well defined, so there isn't a straightfoward answer.  I prefer @bashrc's answer, but if you insist on having two lambdas, this variation might do the job:

```
extern int (*f)(int n);

auto g = [](int n)
{
    if (n >= 5) return n;
    return f(n + 1);
};

int (*f)(int n) = [](int n)
{
    if (n >= 5) return n;
    return g(n + 1);
};

int main()
{
    f(1);
    return 0;
}
```